# Prepping for Tenure in Academic Medical Center

Tags: publications, tenure-track

I'm an early-career assistant professor on the tenure track in a medical department at a school of medicine. My FTE is split 70% for research and 30% for clinical. The 70% FTE in research is soft money, whereas my billed clinical services cover the other portion. Because clinical provision is kind of nebulous and difficult to quantify, especially for my specialty, I'm guessing that my tenure packet will be considered as if I am 100% research. Is that fair or realistic? Does anyone have any insight into such a situation? I've asked for hard numbers regarding pubs, grants, etc, but leadership is reluctant to provide such given the wide ranging discipline-specific differences in productivity. It would suck to hear that I just have to do as much as if I were 100% research.

Comment: I think you need local advice from a tenured mentor who's been through the process both personally and on tenure committees. You should **not** expect hard numbers on anything because that's not how decisions are made. (I may be making some US-centric assumptions)